# Group entries by section

Tags: entries, group

How do I group entries by section? I have search results:

```
{% set entries = allowedSearchableEntries.search(query).order('score').limit(100) %}
```

But I want to have

**SECTION NAME**
entry 1
entry 4
entry 6

**SECTION NAME**
entry 3
entry 12

etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Twig [group filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group).

```
{% set entries = allowedSearchableEntries.search(query).order('score').limit(100) %}

{% set entriesBySection = entries|group('section') %}

{% for section, entriesInSection in entriesBySection %}
    <h2>{{ section }}</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entriesInSection %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Do you know also how I could change the order of sections before doing the group filter? Currently it pulls from the section order in the CP.