# Sorting Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, craft3, sorting

I realize this is a very general question but is there a way to sort a matrix field? So not alphabetically but a very certain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not seen this before, but it's the solution to my problem as I was dealing with grouping.  See link below.

[Group entries by section](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19046/group-entries-by-section)